# What are the precautions to be taken while creating a clearcase component?

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I am trying to create components in a vob for the upcoming project.

What are the common mistakes people make while creating those components?

Do I have to select a view and the root directory to make a component?
I think the root directory will be same as the pvob. Can I select any view here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Vob component vs. root-based component: declaring a *all* vob as one component doesn't scale well when you have many component to declare (each vob component would involve its own `vob_server` process, which consumes resources on the server).
  It is better to use a generic-named vob in order to declare in its (direct) sub-directory components.
- The name of the root directory of the component **cannot be changed** once the component is created: better make it right the first time
- The component need to be created in the *first* directory level of a Vob:
  `myVob/myComponent1`,
  `myVob/myComponent2`, ...
  So the naming convention should reflect that.
  You cannot declare components within a directory like: `myVob/Apache/Cmp1`. You might want to name it `myVob/Apache_Cmp1`.
- "root directory will be same as the pvob": no: you should keep the pvob separate from the vob.

  - The vob contains *data* (files and directory, like the root directory of your component).
  - The pvob contains *metadata*, like the UCM names (of your UCM projects, Streams, Components, Activities, ...)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9579131/6309, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9581762/6309, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14352365/6309